# Checking windows activation state returns wrong value

Tags: c++, winapi, activation

I am building a desktop app for windows 10 that checks whether windows is activated. I am using a method found on another thread to check the activation state, which works but only when it is called within a few seconds of creating a window. Weird, I know. Does anyone know what might cause this, and if there is anything I can do to fix it? Any help is appreciated.

```
bool isGenuineWindows()
{
    //WindowsAppId
    unsigned char uuid_bytes[] = {0x35, 0x35, 0x63, 0x39, 0x32, 0x37, 0x33, 0x34, 0x2d, 0x64, 0x36,
                                0x38, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x34, 0x64, 0x37, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x39, 0x38, 0x33,
                                0x65, 0x2d, 0x64, 0x36, 0x65, 0x63, 0x33, 0x66, 0x31, 0x36, 0x30,
                                0x35, 0x39, 0x66};

    GUID uuid;
    SL_GENUINE_STATE state;

    UuidFromStringA(uuid_bytes, &uuid);
    SLIsGenuineLocal(&uuid, &state, nullptr);
    return state == SL_GEN_STATE_IS_GENUINE;
}

int main(void)
{
      /*creates GUI and all that boring stuff*/
      MessageBox(NULL, "Some random message", "message", MB_ICONERROR);
      printf("%d", isGenuineWindows()); //works
      Sleep(5000); //wait a bit for the magic to wear off
      printf("%d", isGenuineWindows()); //always returns true regardless of activation state
      MessageBox(NULL, "Some random message", "message", MB_ICONERROR);
      printf("%d", isGenuineWindows()); //works again
}
```

Comment: You don't check return values. That's how you tell whether the function succeeded. Your string is not null terminated. Why don't you use a string, easier to see what it actually is. But step 1, add the missing error checking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Return values are being checked. They are just printed out as 0 or 1 with the printf. It's not the ideal way to do it but they are checked. `return state == SL_GEN_STATE_IS_GENUINE;` @Zachary what do you mean by ` //works ` then `//always returns true ` Is printf printing two separate values for you? Is it always returning true because your windows is activated? Is printf returning false and second true? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Nina No, return values of api calls are not checked

Comment: @Nina The first printf returns the true activation state. the second is always true whether windows is activated or not. after the messagebox is opened again it prints the correct output. for example if windows is not activated it would print 010 if it is activated it would print 111. I know that printf isn't a good way to do this, it's just a proof of concept.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right, I should check the return from SLIsGenuineLocal for errors, but I just didn't implement it here. I have checked the return previously, and there are no errors.

Comment: There's not a lot of point in trying to debug winapi code without error checking.

Comment: Are you just suggesting to add something like `if(SLIsGenuineLocal(&uuid, &state, nullptr) != S_OK) return -1;` obviously changing return type to int.

Comment: Every single api call should have error checking. I still don't know why your uuid string isn't null terminated. I don't know why you use ASCII code instead of a simple string literal.

Comment: TBH this is how I have seen it done. I had assumed that there was a good reason, but I'm a novice when it comes to windows APIs. I'm glad you pointed it out, and I will try it how you suggested.

Comment: This is the problem when you just copy code without really understanding it. It's worth taking the time to understand.

Comment: You're right. I should have caught that. I tested it using a null terminated string instead of a byte array and now it works fine. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: If you'd checked for errors in the API calls then you'd have got an error on UuidFromString and so massively narrowed down the problem. As a regular here I can state that at least 95% of winapi questions have code that omits error checking and is therefore needlessly hard to debug. That's the lesson to be learnt here. Anyway, good that you've got a fine chance to learn it!

Comment: Good to know. Lesson learned I guess. :-\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st parameter's type of `UuidFromStringA` is RPC_CSTR, which is defined in rpcdce.h:

```
typedef _Null_terminated_ unsigned char __RPC_FAR * RPC_CSTR;
```

It's a NULL-Terminated string although it is not documented.
If the parameter is not NULL-Terminated, the function will fail. The string you have passed is not NULL-Terminated which will causes undefined behavior(depends on the original value of uuid_bytes[36]).

Use the plaintext string instead of ASCII, which is default NULL-Terminated string:

```
unsigned char uuid_bytes[] = "55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f";
```